# How to get ID of an element in jQuery, which is being clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a scenario, wherein, I have a table and in some columns I have some hidden divs. Now in one of these columns I have a Div which contains another hidden div. Now I cannot apply a generalised function which will just show all divs within a particular row or even within a particular column. I would like to have a function which would detect the id or class of element which is being clicked upon. How to go about this ?

Comment: Can you show us some example code? Maybe code it up in jsfiddle.

Comment: it's it's being clicked... it should be visible, no? how can you click on an hidden div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this, onclick event of the element:

```
<div id="div1" onclick="getId();"> </div>;

function getId(){
     var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, coz if I access it's function by using it's ID, If I modify id of that div, I will have to make changes in the js file. But in this case, the element and it's function lies together, so easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
$(<selector>).click(function() {
  id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You do it like this;

```
$("div").click(function(){

alert($(this).attr("id"));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').bind('click', function(){ // Make this part as specific as it can be
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

You can make your initial selector a bit more restrictive because selecting all divs on a page and assigning an event handler to them is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This will log the ID of the element that was clicked.  You can then add additional logic as shown to handle the "show" functionality.

```
$('div').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id');
    //other logic here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".class").click(function(){
    var clicked = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

could help